# Why does unrelated history appear when running a "git log -m --follow" on a file after merging in multiple repos into one monolithic repository?

Tags: git, commit, bundles, monorepo, git-history

I have several distinct git repos that I'd like to merge together into one monolithic repo while retaining their histories.  I've found a way to do this but I am a little confused about what git log is showing me for a single files history.

Here is the output that I had:

***`git log --oneline`***

**output from combined repo**

```
------- (HEAD -> master) Merge repoC into mono repo
------- Merge repoB into mono repo
------- Merge repoA into mono repo
------- initial commit
------- Add README to repoC
------- Add README to repoB
------- Add README to repoA
```

***`git log --oneline repoA/README.md`***

**output from combined repo**

```
------- Merge repoA into mono repo
```

***`git log --oneline -m --follow repoA/README.md`***

**output from combined repo**

```
 ------- (from -------) (HEAD -> master) Merge repoC into mono repo
 ------- (from -------) Merge repoB into mono repo
 ------- (from -------) Merge repoA into mono repo
 ------- (from -------) Merge repoA into mono repo
 ------- initial commit
 ------- Add README to repoC
 ------- Add README to repoB
 ------- Add README to repoA
```

**Starting with all the separate repos as bundles I do the following to create my monolithic repo:**

For Repos A/B/C

```
git init
echo "repo" > README.md
git add .
git commit -m 'Add README to repo'
git bundle create ../repo{A,B,C}.bundle --all
```

Create combined repo
    git init
    echo "initial" > README.md
    git add .
    git commit -m 'initial commit'

For each repo

```
mkdir repo{A,B,C}
git fetch ../repo{A,B,C}.bundle master
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s ours --no-commit FETCH_HEAD
git read-tree --prefix=repoA -u FETCH_HEAD
git commit -m "Merge repo{A,B,C} into mono repo"
```

Why do I get unrelated git commit history for specific files when running with '-m --follow'? I expect to only see commits that pertain to the file.

UPDATED (trying logs for files with different names and contents):

```
  git log -m --follow --oneline repoB/sue.md`
  -------(from  -------) (HEAD -> master) Merge repo C into mono repo`
  -------(from  -------) Merge repo B into mono repo`
  -------(from -------) Merge repo B into mono repo`
```

Comment: What makes you think those commits are unrelated?  They all created a file at that path according to what you've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on [Mark Adelsberger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700988/why-does-unrelated-history-appear-when-running-a-git-log-m-follow-on-a-file#comment88412406_50700988), you should understand that in Git, the *identity* of a file is defined in a rather curious fashion.

*File identity* in version control systems (VCSes) is a core concept.  How is a VCS supposed to know that file `include/lib.h` is, or is not, "the same" file as file `lib/lib.h`?

Some VCSes take the approach that when a file is *first introduced* into the VCS, you tell the VCS something special, such as `hg add path`.  From then on, any time the file is *renamed*, you *also* tell the VCS something special, such as `hg mv [--after] old-name new-name`.  The VCS can use this to track the identity of the file across some series of commits: `lib/lib.h` in revision X is, or is not, "the same" file as `include/lib.h` in rev R, depending on whether you've told the VCS that there was a rename operation between R and X.

Git, on the other hand, does something radically different: it tries to identify file-pairs, given any two revisions, by *content*.  That is, given revisions R and X as a pair, Git looks at *every file in R* and *every file in X*.  If both *R* and *X* have files named `include/lib.h`, well, that is almost certainly *the same* file, so therefore `lib/lib.h` (in either R or X) is definitely not *the same* file as `include/lib.h` (in the other revision), but it might be the same file as `lib/lib.h` (in the other revision).  However, if exactly one of the two revisions has `include/lib.h` and the other has `lib/lib.h`, that file *might have been renamed* between those two revisions.

In general, for CPU-time-related reasons, given any pair of revisions, if some path *P* exists in both revisions, Git assumes the file was not renamed.  With `git diff`—but not `git merge` and not `git log`—you can add a flag to say *don't assume files were not renamed just because they exist in both revisions*.  This is the `-B` (break pairings) parameter.

Then, as long as *rename detection* is enabled (`-M` option in `git diff`, `--follow` in `git log`, and various other conditions): for all files that are *un*-paired, either because of `-B` or because the given path only exists in one of the two revisions, Git looks for files with *similar content*, computing a "similarity index" for them, and/or *similar names*.  (There's a +1 bonus for matching component names, if both files end in `/lib.h` for instance.  As a key optimization, because it's easy to do internally and it works well, Git will quickly pair files with 100%-identical content, and only after this fails, compute the similarity index.)  It then pairs any files with a similarity index that meets or exceeds the percentage requirement you gave it: `-M50` is the default, but you can require "75% similarity" with `-M75`, for instance.

These paired-up files are "the same" files in the two revisions.  That's true for `git diff`, which then produces a diff between the paired-up files, and for a typical `git merge`, which runs *two* `git diff`s, one from the merge base to one of the two tip commits, and then a second one from that same merge base to the other of the two tip commits.  Most importantly, for `--follow`, it's true for `git log` as well: the paired-up file names direct the `--follow` operation to *change the file name it is looking for* if the file in the earlier revision has a *different* name.

(Your `merge -s ours` is *not* a typical merge: the `ours` strategy ignores all but the HEAD commit when computing the source code to go with the new commit, so it does not bother with any diff-ing at all.)

#### How this affects `git log --follow`

For `git log --follow path` to follow the file whose path name is *path* across renames, Git must do these pair-at-a-time diffs so that it can detect that the file was in fact renamed.  The pairs used are *parent of C* and *C itself*, where *C* is the commit found due to the graph walk, i.e., the commit that `git log` is about to show, or not show, depending on whether it touched a file whose path name is *path*.

Merge commits present a problem here.  The very definition of a merge commit is that it has at least *two* parents.  This is where the `-m` (split a merge) option comes in: splitting a merge means to pretend, for the duration of this one `git log` operation, that the merge commit, with *N* parents, is actually *N* separate different commits.  The first of these *N* commits has one parent: the first parent of the merge.  The second commit has one parent: the second parent of the merge.  The N'th commit has the N'th parent as a single parent, and so on.  So if the merge has three parents, it's split into three virtual commits, each with one parent.

This resolves the pairing problem: each of these virtual commits now has only *one* parent, and Git can run the diff the usual way, to detect any renames.  If Git *finds* a rename, that just means that when it goes to show the *parent* commits—after finishing up with each of these *N* virtual commits—it should stop looking for the path name *path*, and start looking instead for a file whose name is the *old* name in the diff.

Since you're looking for `repoA/README.md`, Git starts out looking for that particular path.  Git *finds* that name, `repoA/README.md`, in the split virtual commit each time it looks.  The parent of each split virtual commit has that file under the name `README.md`, so after Git prints the split virtual commit once per parent—each parent/child pair has `repoA/README.md` in it since each such child commit (the merge itself) has `repoA/README.md` in it—it moves on to the parents, one at a time, looking now for the file named `README.md`.  It finds that each parent commit has such a file, so it prints each parent commit.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. Given that there is no real per file tracking, can you think of any way to help retain histories as I collapse repos into a monolithic repo? In my real case, I have 30+ repos and getting file history gets really obfuscated by all the merge commits and conflicting histories. I am trying to avoid git subtrees if I can.

Comment: Your only real option is to rewrite the earlier repositories so that the names do not coincide (since Git takes "path P exists in both revisions" as the main indicator that the files are "the same"). Both filter-branch and subtree can do this kind of rewriting.

Comment: Even with files with different names and content we still see all merge commits when viewing the log of a file. See edit up top.

Comment: You'll have to *avoid* using `--follow`, or avoid `-m`, or rely on history simplification to prune side branches (this last strategy is ... complicated, I would to try to avoid it), if the different repositories have files that are too similar.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think we are going to go down the git filter tree route to clean up the commit history and remove the merge commits we don't want.